# Is there a way to make MPI implementations agile?

Tags: deep-learning, mpi

The MPI standard today is not fault-tolerant. If we need to scale up or scale down, the entire workload needs to be restarted.

Is there a way the scaling can be handled without having to restart?. This is wrt Deep learning training scenarios. Most DL frameworks use MPI today.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you are mixing several concepts

- [agile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) is a software development approach
- [Fault tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_tolerance) enables a system to continue operations in the event of a failure. MPI is not fault tolerant (yet) but there is an [active working group](https://github.com/mpiwg-ft/ft-issues) addressing this
- Fault tolerance cannot be used to scale up or scale down a simulation.

You might be referring to Elasticity (as in [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud)), and this is something that has to be built into the application. Typically, your application should be checkpointable **and** able to be restarted on a different number of nodes/tasks. That might be achievable "on-the-fly" but it has other implications (how to notifiy the application more or less nodes are available ?)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, there are several ongoing projects which deal with MPI malleability (changing the number of processes on-the-fly).

In this [article](https://doi.org/10.1109/ICPPW.2017.36) you will find the most updated state of art (to the best of my knowledge) and a solution for implement malleability in your applications, because so far, it cannot be done automatically.

Hope it helps.